# 404 Page not found Django even though it is in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I don't know why I am getting a 404 error on the page flights/1 when clearly, I have a url pattern for
`<int:flight_id>` (flights is a app). Help!

My urls.py for the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('flights/', include('flights.urls'))
]
```

My urls.py for the flights app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>", views.flight, name="flight"),\
]
```

And the views.flight

```
def flight(request, flight_id):
    flight = Flight.objects.get(id=flight_id)

    return render(request, "flights/flight.html", {
        "flight": flight,
        "passengers": flight.passengers.all(),
        "non_passengers": Passenger.objects.exclude(flights=flight).all()
    })
```

Template

```
{% extends "flights/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    
    <h1>Flight {{ flight.id }}</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Origin: {{ flight.origin }}</li>
        <li>Destination: {{ flight.destination }}</li>
        <li>Duration: {{ flight.duration }}</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Passengers</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for passenger in passengers %}
            <li>{{ passenger }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No passengers.</li>
        {% endfor%}
    </ul>

    <h2>Add Passenger</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'flight' flight.id book %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="passengers">
            {% for passenger in non_passengers %}
                <option value="{{ passenger.id }}">{{ passenger }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>

    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Back to Flight List</a>
{% endblock %}
```

With layout.html being html boilerplate code

Comment: Assuming you have debug mode turned on, you should get a list of the URLs Django tried. Can you share that, it might give more insight into the problem.

Comment: Is `flights` definitely included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your template too?

Comment: @RobinZigmond the urls django tried are ```admin/```,
```flights/ [name='index']```,
```flights/ <int:flight_id> [name='flight']``` and flights is included in my INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Are you sure a flight with the ID you provide in URL exists?